Hodge bundles associated to a family of complex manifolds
I'm reading Voisin's books on Hodge theory. In the first volume she claimed but didn't prove this theorem:
Theorem 10.10 (Voisin) Let $\varphi:\chi\rightarrow B$ be a family of compact complex manifolds, and $\mathcal{E}^\cdot$ be a complex of vector bundles over $\chi$ satisfying the following condition: given an integer $k$, suppose on each fiber the $k$-th hypercohomology group $\mathbb{H}^k(X_b,\mathcal{E}^\cdot|_{X_b})$ is of constant rank over $B$. Then $R^k\varphi_* \mathcal{E}^\cdot$ is a locally free sheaf of finite rank over $B$, whose fiber tensor with the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{b,B}$ is $\mathbb{H}^k(X_b,\mathcal{E}^\cdot|_{X_b})$. If $\mathcal{F}^\cdot$ is a complex of subbundles of $\mathcal{E}^\cdot$ satisfying the same conditions as above, and on each fiber, the induced hypercohomology map is injective at $\mathbb{H}^k$, then $R^k\varphi_* \mathcal{F}^\cdot\rightarrow R^k\varphi_* \mathcal{E}^\cdot$ is an inclusion of vector bundles.
Here in this theorem we need to assume the mappings in the complex $\mathcal{E}^\cdot$ must be maps of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. I know when both $\chi$ and $B$ are smooth varieties, and $\varphi$ is a smooth projective morphism, the theorem has a not difficult proof, basically using the proof of proposition 9.15 in the same book. But I don't know whether there is a simple proof in complex analytic case.
Now comes my main question:
Associated to any family of compact Kahler complex manifolds, i.e., $\varphi$ is a proper submersion, we can form the Hodge bundle on $B$, which is $\mathcal{H}^k=R^k\varphi_*\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_B$, and it comes with a Hodge filtration by Hodge sub bundles $F^p \mathcal{H}^k\subset \mathcal{H}^k$ (we may need more assumptions, like the total space has a form that restricts to every fiber is a Kahler form, but just assume the sub bundles exist).
My questions are:

Voisin on p.246 says since the complex $(\Omega_{\chi/B}^\cdot,d_{\chi/B})$ is a resolution of the inverse image sheaf $\varphi^{-1}\mathcal{O}_B$, then I know that $R^k\varphi_*\Omega_{\chi/B}^\cdot \cong R^k\varphi_* (\varphi^{-1}\mathcal{O}_B)$. But how to see the last one is isomorphic to the Hodge bundle $R^k\varphi_*\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_B$ easily? This is a local question, topologically $\chi$ is just a product of smooth manifolds, so I guess you can see the isomorphism locally using Cech cohomology. But is there a nicer explanation to see this instead of using Cech cocycles?

The problem of the complex $(\Omega_{\chi/B}^\cdot,d_{\chi/B})$ is that the mappings here are not $\mathcal{O}_X$-module maps, so I guess we can't use the Theorem 10.10 I. mentioned above. On page 250 Voisin says "$F^p\mathcal{H}^k$ is simply equal to
$$R^k\varphi_*\Omega_{\chi/B}^{\cdot\geq p} \subset R^k\varphi_*\Omega_{\chi/B}^\cdot,  $$
admitting Theorem 10.10". But the problem is that Theorem 10.10 is about maps between vector bundles, in particular $\mathcal{O}_X$-module maps, so the proof that I know (proposition 9.15 in the book) doesn't apply in this case.

Is there a simple proof of Theorem 10.10 in the complex-analytic case?



I think 1 is a special case of the projection formula $R^k f_* ( F \otimes f^* G) = R^k f_* F \otimes G$ for $F = \mathbb C$ and $G = \mathcal O_B$.

@WillSawin That's what I thought about before, but the problem in 1 is that, it is a resolution of $\phi^{-1} \mathcal{O}_B$, not the pullback of the structure sheaf on B, so I can't use projection formula, where in the formula you need $f^*$ not $f^{-1}$, and the sheaf G to be finite locally free?

There's a version of the projection formula for sheaves that are not sheaves of modules (or, equivalently, for sheaves of modules over the constant sheaf of rings) in which case $f^*= f^{-1}$. For example look at https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B54 and take the sheaf of rings to be just $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb Z$) instead of the structure sheaf.

@WillSawin Thank you very much, I'll think about it. I agree that it should be some kind of projection formula, but I still feel something is not right. I take a look of your reference and in there we need some kind of finiteness condition on the sheaf G, but here $\mathcal{O}_B$ is not "finite" (in whatever sense) over $\mathbb{C}$...

Oh, good point about perfectness.
